# Why IE8 doesn't understand my css

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-8

I have the following code, and I don't understand what is wrong, what is that IE8 don't like about it

```
var flap = $("#flap");
var animationSupport = _g.animationDetection();

if(animationSupport) {
    flap.addClass("showAnimation");
}
else {
    flap.css('width', flap.width() + 'px').css('right', '-' + flap.width() + 'px');
    flap.animate({right: 0}, 1500);
}
```

When I do this, I have the message:

```
Object doesn't support property or method 'width'
```

Though , if I do the following, seems to be fine:

```
$("#flap").css("width", "300px").css("right", "-300px");
```

Comment: IE <=8 doesn't like a lot of things... :(

Comment: IE does not understand your CSS because it is IE.

Comment: Why would you want to set the flap width to his own width? That seems redundant...

Comment: Try to change it to `fap.width` or `fap.css('width')`

Comment: The error is not related to CSS, that's a Javascript-error.

Comment: @ItayGal It will explicitly set's element width, when there is no width in css

Comment: Cause the flap changes the width, depending on a text that its inside. And I only need JQuery on IE, cause I am doing the animation in CSS3

Comment: Have you tried it in other browsers?

Comment: Does this give you an error? `$("#flap").width()`

Comment: Maybe this helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16564123/806975

Answer (score 0):

I think the .width() might not be supported by IE8. Try this :

```
flap.css('width', flap.css('width')).css('right', '-' + flap.css('width'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember to add ie8 support code in body and head